# Java - Read file by chunks?

Tags: java, sockets, io, inputstream

I know how to read a file by bytes but cannot find a example how to read it in chunks of bytes. I have a byte array, and i want to read the file by 512bytes and send them over a socket.

I have tried by reading total bytes of file and then subtracting 512 bytes until i got a chunk that was less than 512 bytes and signaled EOF and end of transfer.

I am trying to implement a TFTP, where data is sent in 512 byte chunks.

Anyhow would be thankful for a example.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You ... read 512 bytes at a time.

```
char[] myBuffer = new char[512];
int bytesRead = 0;
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("foo.txt"));
while ((bytesRead = in.read(myBuffer,0,512)) != -1)
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't a byte buffer be more appropriate?

Comment: I'd buy you a beer. Cheers mate!

Answer (score 8):

You can use the appropriate `read()` method from the input stream, for example [`FileInputStream`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/FileInputStream.html#read%28byte%5B%5D%29) supports a `read(byte[])` to read a chunk of bytes.

something like: You may want to wrap the input stream in a `BufferedInputStream` if you wanted to guarantee 512 byte blocks (the constructor takes a block size argument).

```
byte[] buffer = new byte[512];
FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream("some_file");
int rc = in.read(buffer);
while(rc != -1)
{
  // rc should contain the number of bytes read in this operation.
  // do stuff...

  // next read
  rc = in.read(buffer); 
}
```

Comment: For every iteration in the loop, you might need a new byte buffer instance; otherwise, if an item count is less than 512, previously saved items will exist in the buffer.

Answer (score -1):

Using `InputStream` you can read in an array of given size and limit the reading to this size.

Read here: [http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html#read%28byte%5B%5D%29)