# How to break down a large text file which is converted into bytes, can be broken down into packets to send over UDP?

Tags: java, udp, byte, datagram

```
public boolean FileToByteArray(DatagramSocket socket, InetAddress dst_addr, int dst_port) throws Exception{
        File file = new File("input.txt");
        InputStream is = new FileInputStream(file);
        long length = file.length();
        byte[] bytes = new byte[(int) length];
        int offset = 0, n = 0;
        DatagramPacket out_pkt = null;

            while (offset < bytes.length && (n = is.read(bytes, offset, bytes.length - offset)) >= 0) {
                offset += n;
                out_pkt = new DatagramPacket(bytes, pkt_size, dst_addr, dst_port);
                packetCount++;
                System.out.println("*****************" + packetCount);
                System.out.println(out_pkt.getLength());
                socket.send(out_pkt);
            }
            is.close();

            String s = new String(bytes);
            System.out.println(s + " " + s.length()) ;
            return true;

      }
```

hi all, I am dealing with an assignment that needs me to send large text file through UDP. 
I am able to read the 10000 byte but when i set pkt_size to 1000, it only delivery 1000 byte which is 1KB of data over. How do i break large file to small packets to send?

Comment: What does "when i set pkt_size to 1000, it only delivery 1000 byte which is 1KB of data over" mean? What did you expect exactly? What's the question here?

Comment: Sorry, what i meant was how do a break down a 1MB text file into packets of 1000 bytes each and send to receiver where the receiver will write it into another file. The end result is input text file must be equal to output text file

Comment: @EJP, I also don't understand the question. Lawrey, you need to read chunks of 1000 bytes from file continiously, then create packet for each chunk in loop and send it.

Comment: You can refer to code for reading chunks in here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9588348/java-read-file-by-chunks