# Find a string in a very large formatted text file in java

Tags: java, regex

Here is the thing:
I have a really big text file and it has a format like this:

```
0007476|000011434982|00249626000|R|2008-01-11 00:00:00|9999-12-31 23:59:59|000019.99
0007476|000014017887|00313865000|R|2011-04-19 00:00:00|9999-12-31 23:59:59|000599.99
...
...
```

And I need to find if a particular pattern exists in the file, say

```
0007476|whatever|00313865000|whatever
```

All I need is a boolean saying yes or no.
Now what I have done is to read the file line by line and do a regular expression matching:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new File(fileName));
        String line;
        while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
            line = scanner.nextLine();
            if (pattern.matcher(line).matches()) {
                scanner.close();
                return true;
            }
        }
```

and the regex has a form of

```
"0007476\|\d{12}\|0031386500.*
```

This method works, but it takes usually 15 seconds to search for a string that is far from the start line. Is there a faster way to achieve that? Thanks

Comment: That's probably the optimal regex. Also, consider asking questions that asks for improvement in existing, working code on [code review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 1):

The [java String class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html) has a contains method which returns a boolean. If your string is fixed, this is a lot faster than a regular expression:

```
if (string.contains("0007476|") && string.contains("|00313865000|")) {
   // whatever
}
```

Hope that helped, if not, leave a comment.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I tried that but the speed difference is negligible. 500ms maximum while it totally takes more than 20 seconds to read the file.

Comment: Have you profiled your code? Do you know where the bottleneck lies?

Answer (score 1):

I assume that you need the `Scanner` because the file is too big to read into a single `String` instead?

If that is **not** the case, you can probably use a regular expression that finds the match directly. Depending on whether or not you care about the specific text at the start of the line you can you something along the lines of:

`"(?m)^0007476\|\d{12}\|0031386500.*$`

If you do need to break it up into smaller chunks because of memory usage I would suggest not reading on a per line basis, (since the lines are rather short), but process bigger chunks using something like a `BufferedReader` instead?

---

I fiddled around a bit with a 1.25GB file and the following is about 2.5 times faster than your implementation:

```
private static boolean matches() throws IOException {
   String regex = "(?m)^0007476\|\d{12}\|0031386500.*$";
   Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);

   try(BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(FILENAME))) {
      for(String lines; (lines = readLines(br, 10000)) != null; ) {
         if (pattern.matcher(lines).find()) {
            return true;
         }
      }
   }

   return false;
}

private static String readLines(BufferedReader br, int amount) throws IOException {
   StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
   int lineCounter = 0;
   for(String line; (line = br.readLine()) != null && lineCounter < amount; lineCounter++ ) {
      builder.append(line).append(System.lineSeparator());
   }

    return lineCounter > 0 ? builder.toString() : null;
}
```

Comment: The file is more than 1GB so it must be separated into chunks. Maybe there is a way to make the chunks contain not one line but several lines together?

Comment: Oh I see the use of BufferedReader. Gonna try that. Thx.

Comment: [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9588348/java-read-file-by-chunks) is a snipped how to read chunks of that file (on a not line by line basis). You will probably need to convert the ```byte[]``` to a ```String``` using ```new String(byteArray)```.

Comment: @Auke: You're using the wrong modifier.  `(?m)` (MULTILINE) is the one that turns `^` and `$` into line anchors.

Comment: @user2403909: the snippet that I linked reads 512 bytes per chunk, which is still rather small. I guess you'll need to play around with the chunks to see if there is an optimum for your situation.

Comment: @Auke: Thx for the reply! The snippet you provided did go faster if the string I am looking for is truly in the file, but it will take really really long time if the string is not in the file.

Comment: There was a bug for the 'false' case, I changed the return statement of the ```readLines()``` method in the snippet above. How's that working out for you?