# Java stream file to socket as fast as possible

Tags: java, sockets, stream

I have a file of bytes `mybytes.dat`, and I'm writing a TCP Server/Client, where the server sends the contents of `mybytes.dat` to the client over a socket.

If `mybytes.dat` is read completely into memory, then the application can send data at about 160MB/s on my local network stack.  However, now I'm trying to stream datafiles that are > 1GB, and shouldn't all be read into memory.

This [related solution for sending a file in chunks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9588348/java-read-file-by-chunks) seems appropriate; however, would it be more efficient to read large chunks of the file into memory (ie. maybe 1MB at a time in a buffer) and then write these as smaller chunks (32kb) to a socket?  If this is reasonable, how can one use a BufferedFileReader to read large chunks, and then write smaller chunks to an OutputStream?  To get started, let me declare at least some variables:

```
BufferedInputStream blobReader = new BufferedInputStream(newInputStream("mybytes.dat"), 1024*1024);
OutputStream socketWriter = socket.getOutputStream();
```

What is the correct way to connect my blobReader to the socketWriter, such that I always maintain enough bytes in memory to ensure the application is not limited by disk reads?  Or am I completely offbase with this line of reasoning?

Comment: I would try [Files.copy](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#copy-java.nio.file.Path-java.io.OutputStream-) or [FileChannel.transferTo](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/channels/FileChannel.html#transferTo-long-long-java.nio.channels.WritableByteChannel-) first.  They’re likely to be as fast as anything you can come up with.

Comment: Awesome, thanks I didn't know about FileChannel.transferTo!

Comment: I'm searching a way to do the opposite: stream a socket into a file AFAP. Any suggestions ?

Comment: There's a buffered file writer object. I'd imagine you'd chain this while buffered socket reader or something along those lines